# Working with TcpClient and Hebrew

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, multiple-languages

I have a VB.NET project.

I am trying to connect to a server through TcpClient.
I am suppose to get data in hebrew - but all the Hebrew returns as symbols...

I am using UTF-8 coding but it doesnt help...
When I tried to change to Unicode - the service got stuck.

Any Ideas?

The code:

```
 client.Connect(Settings.ServerIP, Settings.ServerPort)
client.GetStream().BeginRead(receiveData, 0, receiveData.Length, AddressOf ReceiveDataCallback, client)
Dim bytesReceived As Int32 = (client.GetStream().EndRead(iar))
Dim NewData As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveData, 0, bytesReceived)
```

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of your problem, or at least a nudge into the correct direction - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7236718/16391

Comment: What encoding is the server sending with?