# Read Visual-ordered RTL Text File

Tags: c#, bidi

I have to read some csv text files into a C# program.
The files have hebrew text in them stored in visual ordering.

ie:
    שלום 123
is stored as:
    םולש 123

what is the best way to flip the hebrew to logical ordering,
In php i could use the `hebrev` function, but cannot find anything similar for c#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Encoding.Converting Latin to Hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236550/c-sharp-encoding-converting-latin-to-hebrew)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, that is an encoding problem, this is a visual/logical order problem.