# Cannot decode text from one encoding to another

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I read some text from html website and need to store the data. I know the source encoding (iso-8859-1) and destination encoding(windows-874) from the website http://alexpad.com/textdecoder

The source text is "áÁèÃÔÁ" and I need to convert it to "แม่ริม"
However the output is always be "??????" which are arrays of [63,63,63,63,63,63]

```
string text = "áÁèÃÔÁ";
Encoding fromEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
Encoding toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-874");
byte[] fromBytes = fromEncoding.GetBytes(text);
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.Convert(fromEncoding, toEncoding, fromBytes);
string result = toEncoding.GetString(toBytes);
```

expected result is "แม่ริม"
actual results is "??????" which is wrong

Comment: Check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/7236718/8711654

Comment: You shouldn't convert anything. The bytes are already how you want them. You just need to interpret them.

Comment: All text in HTML is Unicode, regardless of the document encoding. So, once you get the appropriate text using an HTML parser, it'll already be in a String, (and of course it won't be áÁèÃÔÁ).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two encodings is a value of 160.  So is one lower case and the other uppercase?

```
            string iso = "áÁèÃÔÁ";
            string[] isoBytes = iso.Select(x => ((byte)x).ToString()).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Iso " + string.Join(",",isoBytes));

            string win = "แม่ริม";
            string[] winBytes = win.Select(x => ((byte)x).ToString()).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Windows " + string.Join(",",winBytes));

            Console.ReadLine();
```